# How to write modified meta data to mp3

Tags: java, mp3, apache-tika

I extracted meta information thru apache tika library, made some changes and now i want to write out changed information to file.

code snippet for extracting is here:

```
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(...));
    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    Parser parser = new Mp3Parser();
    ParseContext parseCtx = new ParseContext();
    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseCtx);
    input.close();

    String[] tags = metadata.names();
```

i make some changes further like:

```
for(String tagName : tags){
 metadata.remove(tagName);
}
```

And finally i want to write modified version. How can i do this?

Comment: create new file using FileOutputStream and write data whatever you read from FileInputStream.

Comment: Is calling out to a command line program an option? That'll be the simplest/easiest way, rather than doing it in pure Java

Comment: yes i tried doing so, but after an error while opening file. i tried to write like this:
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToProcess);
IOUtils.copy(input, outputStream);
input.close();
outputStream.close();